# React does not recognize the gapMode prop on a DOM element when using an elastic ui modal

Tags: reactjs

I am developing a react application using the elastic ui library. The problem is that when I try to show a modal I get a weird error saying "React does not recognize the `gapMode` prop on a DOM element". But I don't pass any prop named `gapMode` to any DOM element.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove `<React.StrictMode>` tag or edit to `<React.Fragment>` from `index.tsx`.

Comment: If I remove the <React.StrictMode> tag the modal appears correctly but the error is still there.

Answer (score 0):

I've received a the same `gapMode` error using React.  It seems to be a property in the [`react-focus-on`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-focus-on) and the [`react-remove-scroll`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-remove-scroll) modules.

I wasn't using these modules explicitly, but I was seeing the error in tests and in the console.  The error was removed from tests if I included the following in `package.json`.

```
"overrides": {
    "react-focus-on": "3.7.0"
},
```